# Same vba macro produce different result on other PC

Tags: excel, vba

```
Sub rename_other_workbookSheet()
Application.EnableEvents = False
Application.ScreenUpdating = False
Application.DisplayAlerts = False


    Dim Path            As String
    Dim FileName        As String
    Dim wb As Workbook
    Dim sht As Worksheet
    Dim ws1 As Worksheet
    
Path = Application.ThisWorkbook.Path

FileName = Dir(Path & "\*.xl*", vbNormal)
Do Until FileName = ""
If InStr(UCase(FileName), "MAPPING_FILE") > 0 Then
Set wb = Workbooks.Open(Path & "\" & FileName)
wb.Activate

For Each sht In wb.Worksheets

    If sht.Name = "Sheet1" Then
        Set ws1 = Worksheets("Sheet1")
        ws1.Name = "Mapping"
        Application.CutCopyMode = False
        ws1.Cells.Copy
        ws1.Cells.PasteSpecial xlPasteValues
        Application.CutCopyMode = False
        End If
        Next sht
        wb.Save
        wb.Close
End If
FileName = Dir()
Loop



Application.EnableEvents = True
Application.ScreenUpdating = True
Application.DisplayAlerts = True

End Sub
```

I am using this macro to search for a workbook name mapping_file, open it and rename the Sheet1 to Mapping, then remove the formulas inside while retain the values.
This macro work wells on my PC but when this macro run on my colleague pc, it wouldn't remove the formula inside. My colleague pc can run other macro file wells but only this macro got problem.

Comment: Did you check if the opened workbooks first sheet is really called "Sheet1" - e.g. on a german Excel it would be called "Tabelle1" by default

Comment: @Ike yes we have tried to execute this file with the same source file and the first Sheet really called "Sheet1"

Comment: On your colleague's PC test the following: Open the file, put a breakpoint in the first line of your macro. Run the macro (it should now stop at that breakpoint). Then go through the code step by step using F8 and check what it actually does vs. what you expect it to do. You can check the content of variables by holding the mouse over them while you are in step by step mode.

Comment: Is this really the code you are using? To me it looks like the for each sht-loop  and the if sht.name are mixed ... Check your indenting too

Comment: @PEH  Oh thanks for this idea, will try this when he back from vacation

Comment: @Ike yes this is the code I used and it works well on my pc

Comment: ... and what about the path in your macro? Is it a local directory or one on a network? An in case of a network directory, are you using mapped drives or UNC (\\servername\directory\...)?

Comment: There is definitly missing an `End If` for `If sht.name = "Sheet1" Then` - if you use correct indenting you will see it.

Comment: @Dominique my path is inside Document and my colleague is using network

Comment: @Gunhanwei: try to do access the file from the network too, just like your colleague. You might do this using a mapped drive, or using UNC path, as mentioned in my previous comment, and see if you experience any problem.

Comment: @Ike Sorry I think I accidentally delete it when copying to here

Comment: @Dominique thanks for the idea , will try this method

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Rename Worksheet in Other Workbooks

**Your Code**

- The '`Instr` business' would not be necessary if you would include it in the `Dir`:

  ```
  FileName = Dir(Path & "\*MaPpIng_fILe*.xl*", vbNormal)
  ```
- Right below the second occurrence of `Application.CutCopyMode = False` there should be...

  ```
      Exit For ' it was found, no need to loop any further
  End If ' the 'closing' part of 'If sht.Name = "Sheet1" Then'
  ```

  the `End If` part being the key mistake.
- You are saving and closing all workbooks, so any of the occurrences of  `Application.CutCopyMode = False` is redundant (try it manually).
- A more efficient way to copy values in place is...

  ```
  rg.Value = rg.Value
  ```

  ... i.e. ...

  ```
  ws1.Cells.Value = ws1.Cells.Value
  ```

  ... possibly even better...

  ```
  ws1.UsedRange.Value = ws1.UsedRange.Value
  ```
- Saving all files (`wb.Save`), even if there was no processing, is also not efficient (takes time).

**This Code**

- A 'matching' file (workbook) is processed only if it **does not contain** a worksheet named `Mapping` but it **contains** a worksheet named `Sheet1`.

```vb
Option Explicit

Sub RenameWorksheetInOtherWorkbooks()
    Const ProcTitle As String = "Rename Worksheet in Other Workbooks"
    
    Const swbNamePattern As String = "*Mapping_File*"
    Const swbExtensionPattern As String = ".xl*"
    Const swsOldName As String = "Sheet1"
    Const swsNewName As String = "Mapping"
    
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    ' If necessary (often not), out-comment the following and their
    ' respective 'closing' ones below ('True').
    'Application.EnableEvents = False
    'Application.DisplayAlerts = False
    
    Dim twb As Workbook: Set twb = ThisWorkbook
    Dim twbName As String: twbName = twb.Name
    
    Dim swbFolderPath As String: swbFolderPath = twb.Path & "\"
    Dim swbDirPath As String
    swbDirPath = swbFolderPath & swbNamePattern & swbExtensionPattern
    Dim swbName As String: swbName = Dir(swbDirPath)
    ' The correct files are already 'chosen', no need to test in the loop.
    
    Dim swb As Workbook
    Dim sws As Worksheet
    Dim swbCount As Long
    Dim swbOldCount As Long
    Dim swbNewCount As Long
    
    Do Until Len(swbName) = 0
        
        ' Test if not 'ThisWorkbook', the workbook containing this code.
        If Not StrComp(swbName, twbName, vbTextCompare) = 0 Then
            
            swbCount = swbCount + 1
            Set swb = Workbooks.Open(swbFolderPath & swbName)
            
            Set sws = Nothing
            On Error Resume Next
            Set sws = swb.Worksheets(swsNewName)
            On Error GoTo 0
            
            ' Test new name.
            If sws Is Nothing Then ' no worksheet with new name
                
                On Error Resume Next
                Set sws = swb.Worksheets(swsOldName)
                On Error GoTo 0
                
                ' Test old name.
                If Not sws Is Nothing Then ' found worksheet with old name
                    ' Only in this case the workbook is processed.
                    swbOldCount = swbOldCount + 1
                    sws.Name = swsNewName
                    sws.UsedRange.Value = sws.UsedRange.Value
                    swb.Save
                Else ' no worksheet with old name
                    Debug.Print swb.FullName
                End If
            
            Else ' found worksheet with new name (previously processed)
                
                swbNewCount = swbNewCount + 1 ' not testing for old name!
            
            End If
            
            swb.Close False
            
        End If
        
        swbName = Dir
    
    Loop
    
    'Application.DisplayAlerts = True
    'Application.EnableEvents = True
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
    
    MsgBox "Total workbooks found: " & swbCount & " (with matching pattern)" _
        & vbLf & "Containing worksheet '" & swsOldName & "': " _
        & swbOldCount & " (just processed)" _
        & vbLf & "Containing worksheet '" & swsNewName & "': " _
        & swbNewCount & " (previously processed)" _
        & vbLf & "Containing neither worksheet: " _
        & swbCount - swbOldCount - swbNewCount _
        & " (if any, check out the list in the 'Immediate window' " _
        & "('VBE Ctrl+G')", vbInformation, ProcTitle

End Sub
```